# ngx-scroll-event installed, but cannot be found

Tags: angular, npm

I just updated my project from Angular 7 to 8 (using ng update and following the Angular update guide), and everything was fine. Then I proceeded to Angular 9 and the project suddenly couldn't find the **ngx-scroll-event@2.0.2** package anymore.
Now it's throwing the "module not found" error:

```
Cannot find module 'ngx-scroll-event' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)
```

Thinking that it might really be a dependency error, I used a few commands to avoid some dependency tree problems, like:

```
npm uninstall ngx-scroll-event
npm install ngx-scroll-event@2.0.2
npm update
npm ci
npm rebuild
npm cache verify
```

Everything was successful, no error was thrown, the package is listed on package.json/package-lock.json AND its folder is present, built on */node_modules*, but when I try to run the project with **ng s**, the error continues. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue after migrating my project to Angular 9. After inspecting the "ngx-scroll-event" inside the node_modules folder, I realized that the "ngx-scroll-event" folder contains another dist folder that contains the library files.

So I changed the import syntax from the 'ngx-scroll-event' to 'ngx-scroll-event/dist/ngx-scroll-event' and it worked just fine.

For example:

```
import {NgxScrollEvent} from 'ngx-scroll-event/dist/ngx-scroll-event';
```

There will be better solution for this issue, but atleast it works.

Comment: After some days searching, the error simply disappeared. I tried to understand what caused this but had no clue. Then recently, once again, the error popped on my terminal and your answer really helped to solve the issue. Thank you very much!